# whats the correct syntax for reading params in express.js with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a url such as

```
  http://localhost:8080/siteinfo.json?site&locationid=1&companyid=1
```

And I want to rout a function and pass the ? params to it. What is the correct syntax?

```
  app.get('/siteinfo.json', getdata_hdlr.get_site_setup);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have not defined your params in your route then it will be:

```
req.param('locationid');
```

But you can create placeholders in your routes such as:

```
app.get("/product/:id", product.show);
```

Then that 'id' param is available in your controller as:

```
req.params.id
```

Answer (score 2):

The query parameters are in the request object already.

```
app.get('/siteinfo.json', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query);
  res.send("locationid="+req.query.locationid+"\ncompanyid="+req.query.companyid);
});
```